# Does installing a game to the Xbox hard drive help solve some of the glitch issues that can be associated with normal disc-only play?

Tags: xbox-360, hard-drive

I play Fallout New Vegas and I'm mainly concerned if installing the game to my HDD would cause the game to run without as much glitching, cause as anyone who plays Fallout knows, the game glitches a whole lot.

Other than Fallout New Vegas or some NCAA with friends I rarely play my Xbox so I'm not really concerned about taking up HDD space and I would say I suffer far less wear and tear than the "average" gamer. If anyone could please give some experienced insight to my question about less glitching I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Hey Jesuserotica, welcome to gaming! In order to get the best answer for your question, I suggest you take the time to improve it a little bit. While the question's title seems rather broad, you are actually asking about a specific game. Did you mean to do that, or does this specific game only serve as an example? Making the title more indicative of the actual question is a very good practice. Also, you may want to make your question a little more "professional", though I can definitely sympathize with your plight and the emotions it evokes.

Comment: duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/719/should-i-install-xbox-360-games-to-my-hard-drive

Comment: @Dave DuPlantis Related but not a duplicate, sounds like Jesuserotica is having trouble with a specific game, but does not specify exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 5):

Glitches are usually caused by bugs in a given game's code, causing unexpected behavior.  Since installing a game to your hard drive doesn't actually modify the code in any way, I can't imagine that it would fix any glitches you have seen.  It IS important, though, to download any updates for the game that are available, as such updates are frequently used to fix known glitches.  Make sure your xbox is connected to the internet when you start a game and it should tell you automatically if there is an update for a given game.

For more information on the benefits of saving games to your hard drive, see [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22404/what-is-the-point-of-installing-a-game/22405#22405)

Comment: Skyrim did have some issues if installed http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/digitalfoundry-skyrim-texture-problems-on-xbox-360

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/719/should-i-install-xbox-360-games-to-my-hard-drive" comment from Maxim Zaslavsky.